# Calling an IBAction from another method

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to Objective-C, Xcode and all of the good stuff. I am self teaching.

I am trying to call an `IBAction` from another method.

```
- (IBAction)strAdj:(UIStepper *)strStepper
{
    // Converts stepper to integer
    NSUInteger strvalue = strStepper.value;

    // Changes the the text to the value of the stepper
    strStat.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2d", (unsigned)strvalue];

    _strMod.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2d", (unsigned)stepperAdj(strvalue)];
    // Based on the value it change the strMod to a specific value
}
```

I am only posting a portion of the next code. It is a simple `switch` statement. I basically want to call the IBAction above in the Void below.

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    switch (row) {
        case 0:
            break;
// Core races never change
        // defines dwarf stats
        case 1:
            // sets all the increases
            tempCon = 2;
            tempWis = 2;
            tempChr = -2;

            // resets all other stats
            tempStr = 0;
            tempDex = 0;
            tempInt = 0;

            // I want to call the IBAction here... 

            break;
```

This `IBAction` will need to occur ultimately 15 times. The above `switch` statement occurs when the picker is changed. Where as the `IBAction` happens every time the stepper occurs.

I hope that I am not too far from what I want to do. Again I have only been working with this for the last several days and I have not been able to find what I am looking for or if I did then I wasn't sure what to do.

Comment: Why do you need to call the stepper action from the picker delegate method?

Answer (score 0):

It kinda looks like you have a dropdown for the player to select a race and each attribute (str, con, wis, etc.) has a stepper to bump the respective values up or down.

I don't know enough to speculate, but I suspect there is a better approach overall.  That said, I think a brute force solution to what you are trying to do is to make sure each of your steppers has a referencing outlet: stepperWis, stepperCon, stepperInt, etc.  Then in your switch you can do something like so (for each attribute):

```
stepperWis.value = (whatever value you want);
[self strAdj:self.stepperWis];
```

Comment: Yes you have this pretty spot on. That is the basic concept of the app. While  I'm sure there is easier ways of doing this, right now I'm still learning and trying to figure out everything. First I just want to get a working copy. Then go back refine it a lot. The issue right now is when I adjust the picker it doesn't update the labels (that the steppers change), but when I change the stepper it updates based of the stepper value. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: One thing I'm not seeing, is how do the labels know which stepper is being updated?  As written, it kind of looks like regardless of which stepper is kicked, the same label is being updated.

Comment: There is a label for each stat. So there are currently 6 steppers. One for each stat. There are 12 labels. 6 for stat scores and 6 for stat modifiers.

The stat modifiers are based on the value of the stat scores. There is an IBAction that does the same thing, except it does it for each stat.

Comment: Ok. So some updates. I have decided I want to pursue Swift, found that Swift is easier for me to learn... And I am choosing to go with a cleaner UI.

Thank you for all of the input and help. It worked with the updates.

Answer (score 0):

You can call UIButton TouchUpInside event programatically like :

[YourButtonObject sendActionsForControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];